# User "ASP" logged in to windows server - hacking attempt?

Tags: windows

I run a windows server 2008 which I connect to both via VNC and via remote desktop. Yesterday I noted when I connected to it via VNC that another user was logged in. See images.

Notes:

- I have no idea what ASP is. It seems to be a guest account when I looked it up in accounts as Administrator.
- I have no idea what "SCOOTER-PC" is.
- I tried my usual passwords to log in as the ASP-user, but these were incorrect.
- I have not seen this before, and as I just recently started using remote desktop I figure it might be that that session somehow is still being active.

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: I think the policy here should be delete the user and ask questions later.

Comment: I changed password on the "ASP" user account and then restarted the server  which included installations of latest updates. Should I still delete the account?

Comment: My best guess is that you server is compromised. [Act accordingly][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: It's your server, if you don't know the user I would delete it.  And run an antivirus on it.

Comment: Many thanks for you replies. I have two follow up questions. 1) If it is compromised, do you have any ball park estimates of the risk that this user, logging in with a guest account, has been able to access the My Documents folder of the Administrator account? 2) why would antivirus help against hackers? Is that to remove any trojans?

Comment: I would assume total compromise.  You could look at the activity of the user and see what they've been doing.  I'd assume that they've installed a rootkit of some sort to ensure future exploitation, so running an antivirus/antimalware program would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Your server seems compromised!

the steps you should take is to immidiatly make a IP scope for the remote desktop and VNC application in windows firewall so only the IPaddress of the remote (or LAN if its in the same network) should be able to acces this!

Also, the user ASP should be deleted at once, be sure to run antivirusses like Malwarebytes and install updates to make sure there isnt a keylogger, and change the passwords for the Admin (and all other users if there are any).

good luck!